# SharePoint 2010 FAST Search Server, Single or Multi?

Tags: search, fast-search

I was looking for some benchmarks on the search capabilities of FAST Search Server to try and determine whether or not we need a single or multi-server environment for FAST Search Server.  Do any exist?  How big of an index have people seen before FAST Search starts to have issues serving queries or indexing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really the best place to look through is [link text](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383304.aspx) as there is no short answer. There's so much good content there, giving you a link to a single document / web page is simply not enough.

From my experience, if you have a small corpus < 50,000 then a single server is sufficient. I've got a pretty noddy server that is nowhere near capacity with that number of items.

Comment: One other thing to note, is that memory is super important. Don't cheap-out with 16gb. Get as much as you can. 

Also, checkout Microsoft's topology planning documentation for help with sizing.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599528.aspx

Comment: You also have to consider redundancy requirements if you need it. If you have one sharepoint server you don't have to care. Just considere the extra boxes if you need some kind of HA.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a hard and fast answer to this.  Individual servers can be configured to handle very demanding search requirements.  The question of multiple servers tends to come up in response to redundancy and the "cost" of losing your search application in the event of an outage.

Answer (score 0):

There is some sizing guidance, but I can't find the link right now.  At a high level, the number of servers are dictated by how many items you have in your index (millions), how many poeple are actively searching, and if you need to setup processing for things like extraction of meta-data.